# How to generate random Y at specific X from a linear model in R?

Tags: r

Say we have a linear model `f1` that was fit to some `x` and `y` data points:

```
f1 <- lm(y ~ x,data=d)
```

How can I generate new `y` values at new `x` values (that are different from the old `x` values but are within the range of the old `x` values) using this `f1` fit in **R**?

Answer (score 5):

`stats:::simulate.lm` allows you to sample from a linear model fitted with `lm`. (In contrast to [the approach of @Bulat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37143607/1870254) this uses unbiased estimates of the residual variance). To simulate at different values of the independent variable, you could hack around like this:

```r
# simulate example data
x <- runif(20, 0, 100)
y <- 5*x + rnorm(20, 0, 10)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

# fit linear model
mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

# new values of the independent variable
x_new <- 1:100

# replaces fitted values of the model object with predictions for new data,
mod$fitted.values <- predict(mod, data.frame(x=x_new)) # "hack" 

# simulate samples appropriate noise and adds it the models `fitted.values`
y_new <- simulate(mod)[, 1] # simulate can return multiple samples (as columns), we only need one

# visualize original data ...
plot(df)
# ... alongside simulated data at new values of the independent variable (x)
points(x_new, y_new, col="red")
```

[image]

(original data in black, simulated in red)

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the same problem.

In simple terms it can be done by using sample from residuals:

```
mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

x_new <- c(5) # value that you need to simulate for.
pred <- predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(x = x_new))
err <- sample(mod$residuals, 1)
y <- pred + err
```

There is a `simulate(fit, nsim = 10, XX = x_new)` function, that is supposed to do it for you.

Comment: Note that the residuals are biased towards 0, so re-sampling is not exactly the same as sampling from the fitted linear model.  Furthermore, you probably meant to write `err <- sample(mod$residuals, size = length(x_new), replace = TRUE)`.

Comment: What is this `XX` argument of `simulate`, I don't see this in the documentation/code of `stats:::simulate.lm`?

Comment: May be it was meant to be 'X', not sure

Comment: `simulate` does not have a `X` argument either. Maybe you had been working with some model class that implements a `simulate` method that accepts new data -- or it was just wishful thinking?

Comment: I didn't spend much time on the problem. Idea was to point towards the right direction. I think more details belong to cross validate site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `predict` for this:

```
x <- runif(20, 0, 100)
y <- 5*x + rnorm(20, 0, 10)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
df
plot(df)

mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

x_new <- 1:100
pred <- predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(x = x_new))
plot(df)
points(x_new, pred)
```

Comment: This answer only explains how to perform predictions at new `x` values, not how to "generate **random** Y" at those.